# Unlock bootloader or flash TWRP with EDL on Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 Pro (kenzo)

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, xiaomi, bootloader-lock

I have a Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 Pro (kenzo) phone with a locked bootloader. Earlier, I unlocked this, but I do this with an easy switcher tumbler "OEM-unlock", so I flashed TWRP, custom ROMs, etc. After this, I flashed one more official MIUI ROM (Android 5.1), and the bootloader was locked.

I tried `fastboot oem unlock`, `fastboot flashing unlock` and other commands to unlock. I unlocked with Mi unlock and many attempts to unlock. Then I flashed the official Android 6.0 ROM with EDL, but when I tried to replace the stock `recovery.img` to TWRP recovery (yes, I renamed the file to `recovery.img`), I still see the stock recovery.

I also unpacked `boot.img` in EDL ROM and replaced `ro.secureboot.devicelock=1` to `ro.secureboot.devicelock=0`, but when I flashed it, it doesn't boot (fastboot only).

How can I unlock the bootloader or flash TWRP with EDL?

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3565172

Comment: OP's own follow-up question: [Flash custom ROM via EDL](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246514/44325).

Answer (score 1):

I find a way to unlock device without waiting. You need to: Mi Account and SIM-card with same number, that registred in Mi-account. Then, you need to link account to device (in internet much of instructions). Then the main step: download another version of Mi Unlock 5.5.0224.55, and unlock with this version. It do next steps: bypass the unlock time, unlock without getting any keys/tokens.