# Flash custom ROM via EDL

Tags: custom-roms, xiaomi

I trying to find any way to flash custom ROM or some images on locked bootloader via EDL (device is Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 Pro, kenzo). I downloaded stock developer fastboot-EDL ROM and modified recovery.img to custom recovery, but when I boot phone, it's reboots again, and I see stock recovery (system partition was bricked). I saw KEYMASTER, CMNLIB and SEC partitions stores some secure-boot hashes. Any way to skip boot verifying? (locked bootloader, EDL, XiaoMiFlash 2017)

Comment: OP's previous question (for additional context): [Unlock bootloader or flash TWRP with EDL on Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 Pro (kenzo)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246440/44325)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to unlock your phone first.
Then use Fastboot to install TWRP and then install your own ROM.
To unlock your phone, go to mi.com and sign up a new account then enter it into your phone and unlock it by mi unlock app:
https://en.miui.com/unlock/
or
https://mega.nz/file/xeQ3GRgQ#DpaEfaUSZZFBCQ6HOitWgQu9EMIl4q_XM8-eChUusbY

Comment: The OP has posted [a question before this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246440/44325) saying that the bootloader cannot be unlocked.

Comment: You have no other choice.